# Cannot Start new activity from a listview

Tags: android

When I click on list item, nothing happens. Why is this and how can I solve it?

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    TextView selection ;
    private String[] menus = {"MainActivity","spam"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list) ;
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menus));  
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_second, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you forget to assigned the `Listener` to the list view write this in your `onCreate` `listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extend ListActivity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

You must override onListItemClick method:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //start activity
    }
```

Also don't forget to extend ListActivity in your activity class.

Edit:

Your class should look like this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends ListActivity{

//onCreate {...}

@Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            //start activity
        }
```

And it is done.

Comment: Cant you fix it for me, i cannot fix@_@.when i override it, error

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i can run it

Answer (score 0):

Set the listener to the listview. That may be helping to solve your problem